# Derivative with single integral of variable limits, but with separate integration variable.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, nonlinear-optimization

Say I have the following:

$$f(t) = \int_0^t{e^{s^3\sin(t)}ds}$$

How do I compute $f'(t)$?

My first thought was to use FTC, but the $s$ variable makes this confusing. I'm not completely sure where partial derivatives would come into play, either, given that $f$ is defined as a single-variable function. I thought [LIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) was the correct approach, but was told I was wrong.

This is homework for a non-linear optimization problem.

**Edit**

When I apply LIR, this is what I get:

$$f'(t)=e^{t^3\sin t}+\int_0^ts^3e^{s^3\sin t}\cos tds$$

Comment: LIR *is* the correct approach.

Comment: Does this mean that my professor is wrong if he's asserting that the method is incorrect?

Comment: What about $$ f(t) = \int_{0}^{\color{red}{1}}t\exp\left(t^3 u^3 \sin t\right)\,du $$ ? In such a case you may simply differentiate the inner function with respect to $t$, since the integration bounds do not depend on $t$ anymore.

Comment: @aboutblank: I'd rather suspect that you applied it in a wrong way :-)

Comment: Are you saying that the integral you've just provided is equivalent to the one I posted?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Reasonable, sure. If this is the case, maybe you could provide input on the update I just made? If you make it an answer I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Looks good to me. Do you have the teacher's answer ?

Comment: This looks perfect to me.